# MongoDB v2.4.9 sort by boolean field

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongoose, database

How do I sort query results based on a boolean field?

Consider the following collection:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "name" : "John" , "isFoo" : true}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "name" : "Jim" , "isFoo" : false}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "name" : "Joel" , "isFoo" : false}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "name" : "Jill" , "isFoo" : true}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "name" : "Samantha" , "isFoo" : true}
```

I need a query that will return the `isFoo == true` first and the `isFoo == false` documents second. In other words, I need to sort by a boolean field.

The following code is does not do the trick as I still get some documents with `isFoo == true` mixed in with the false ones.

```
db["users"].find().sort( { isFoo: 1 } )
```

Ideas?

Comment: I just tested it on mongodb v2.2.0 and works fine as expected. (I tested using the native console, not mongoose)

Comment: It works fine in v2.4.9 as well.  `sort({isFoo:1})` returns false documents first and `sort({isFoo:-1})` returns true documents first.

Comment: *bashes head into wall* Turns out I have some bad documents in the collection where the field isFoo has been registered as a string. Now I have to figure out how to change the type of the field.

Comment: A quick forEach finding all by BSON type not bool should do it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code above works, my data was bad. 
As I wrote in the comment above, some of the documents had isFoo as a String (not Boolean) and that's why I was seeing the mixed results.

I had to change the type of the field from String to Boolean so I tried this:

```
db.users.find( { 'isFoo' : { $exists : true } } ).forEach( function (x) {   x.isFoo = new Boolean(x.isFoo);    db.users.save(x); });
```

But that just turned all of the isFoo fields to Objects.

Seeing as I was really tired of dealing with this issue I just used the following to set all the isFoo fields to false and just handle the changes manually.

```
db.users.find( { 'isFoo' : { $exists : true } } ).forEach( function (x) {   x.isFoo = false;    db.users.save(x); });
```

This was very annoying.