# how to get specific documents first and then rest in a mongodb?

Tags: database, mongodb, go

suppose my product collection look like this,

```json
[

    {
          "id":1,
          "name":"laptop",
          "offer":false,
       },
    
       {
          "id":2,
          "name":"mobile",
          "offer":true,
          "offerEnd":"2-4-2022",
       },
    
       {
          "id":3,
          "name":"washing machine",
          "offer":false
       },
    
       {
          "id":4,
          "name":"t.v",
          "offer":false
       },
         {
          "id":5,
          "name":"refrigenerator",
          "offer":true,
          "offerEnd":"2-4-2025",
       },
       
       {
          "id":6,
          "name":"drone",
          "offer":false
       },

   
   ....
   ....

]
```

There you can see some product have offer(true) and other don't (false) here I want the offered documents (i.e. flag true) come first and then rest in a descending orders.

please let me know the query ?

Comment: is it okay to sort after query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB v2.4.9 sort by boolean field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813322/mongodb-v2-4-9-sort-by-boolean-field)

Comment: I want to order whole documents in descending

Comment: Is this a Go question?  Or purely a mongodb question?

Comment: it is purely in mongodb. Go is  backend

Answer (score 0):

Mongodb has the `$orderby` operator, with go you can use the `findOptions` to sort the results in ascending or descending order.
Here is an example:

```
findOptions := options.Find()
// Sort by `offer` field descending
findOptions.SetSort(bson.D{{"offer", true}})


db.Collection("myCollection").Find(nil, bson.D{}, findOptions)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply @NelsonThiago. Your query will yield every items sort with offer value instead I want to sort all items with descending order and  put offered item first from that order