# How to use conditional statement for sort in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, go

let me illustrate with an example,
suppose my collection is like this,

```
products = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "a",
        offer: true,
        expiryDate: "23-03-2022"
    },

    {
        id: 2,
        name: "b",
        offer: false,//no offer

    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "c",
        offer: true,
        expiryDate: "01-01-2021"//already expired
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: "d",
        offer: true,
        expiryDate: "01-06-2022"
    },
]
```

I want here, the offered items comes first in descending order,
it should not expire and then the remaining item should come in
descending order so result would be like this

```
   [


    {
        id: 4,
        name: "d",
        offer: true,
        expiryDate: "01-06-2022"
    },
    {
        id: 1,
        name: "a",
        offer: true,
        expiryDate: "23-03-2022"
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: "c",
        offer: true,
        expiryDate: "01-01-2021"
    },

    {
        id: 2,
        name: "b",
        offer: false,

    },


]
```

Comment: Your issue is similar to this one, have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813322/mongodb-v2-4-9-sort-by-boolean-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {}
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "offer": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": {
            "$lt": [
              {
                "$toDate": "$expiryDate"
              },
              "$$NOW"
            ]
          },
          "then": false,
          "else": true
        }
      },
      "expiryDate": {
        "$toDate": "$expiryDate"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "expiryDate": -1,
      "offer": -1
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZOJwpGCWjXJ)

Comment: sort should be "$sort": {
      "offer": -1,
      "id": -1,
      
    }